# Location is always null when reading an event

Tags: java

So I'm working on a Ticketing System but for some reason I can't seem to get a location in my events.

The TicketingSystem class has some hashmaps where I add my data to.
It also has reader methods the one I'm having trouble with is readEvents().

```
public TicketSystem() {
    queueService = new QueueService();
    users = new HashMap<>();
    locations = new HashMap<>();
    events = new HashMap<>();
    readData();
}

public void addLocation(Venue location) {
    locations.put(location.getId(), location);
}

public void addEvent(Event event) {
    events.put(event.getId(), event);
}

public static Event getEvent(String eventId) {
    return events.get(eventId);
}

public static Venue getLocation(String locationId) {
    return locations.get(locationId);
}

public void readLocations() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("venuedata.txt"))) {
        String line = "";
        VenueMapper mapper = new VenueMapper();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Venue venue = mapper.map(line.split(";"));
            locations.put(venue.getId(), venue);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readEvents() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("eventdata.txt"))) {
        String line = "";
        EventMapper mapper = new EventMapper();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Event event = mapper.map(line.split(";"));
            events.put(event.getId(), event);
            reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readData() {
    readEvents();
    readLocations();
}
```

With an EventMapper class which reads data from a text file through the TicketingSystem class split by ";" data[5] is my locationId.

```
@Override
public Event map(String[] data) {
    String dateAndTime = data[1];
    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder(dateAndTime.substring(0, 8));
    StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder(dateAndTime.substring(8));

    return new Event(data[0], data[2], date.toString(), time.toString(), data[3], Double.parseDouble(data[4]), data[5]);
}
```

}

This is my event class which contains the constructor I'm using returning the event in the EventMapper class

```
public Event(String id, String name, String date, String time, String description,
        double price, String locationId) {
    this(name, LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy")),
            LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm")), description, price);    
    this.id = id;
    *setLocation(TicketSystem.getLocation(locationId));*
}

public void setLocation(Venue location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

Everytime I debug there's data in the locations list but for some reason my events aren't picking up the locations I'm trying to get.

Comment: Please consider trimming that into a valid [mcve]

Comment: I "think" part of the problem is the use of `static` in `TicketSystem`, which seems to allow you to use the class as either a instance class or a static class, but which only initialises the fields when you create an instance, which is just all confusing. You might consider investigating the use of a singleton instead

Comment: I'd also verify that the location information is been loaded into the `locations` map and that the `id`s are matching

Comment: The location information is loading into the locations map no problems with that.